# Casting str in Scientific Notation to Float fails only on Positive numbers in Python

Tags: python

I am reading in a couple of columns from a text file (delimited by 3 spaces for some reason)

The columns are in scientific notation. The first column has a mixture of positive and negative numbers.

When casting to float in this segment:

```
    count = 0
    curfile = open(curFile, "r")    
    for row in curfile.readlines():
       if count > (row_first-1) and count < row_last:
           line = row.split('   ')
           x.append(float(line[0]))
          print line[0]
           y.append(float(line[1]))
           count = count + 1
       else:
           count = count + 1
```

it fails when switching from a negative row to a positive row for the first column

```
-3.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00   
-1.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00   
 1.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00
```

so in this case it will successfully convert -1(the second row) but not 1(the third row). 
when appending values to Y which are all positive, this problem does not occur.

I thought maybe there was a blank space before the positive numbers where the 
"-" sign was but using lstrip() on the string did not help.

I am totally perplexed by this issue and would appreciate any ideas.

Edit: The exception that gets thrown when I run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\scripts\flow3d_script\flow_3d.py", line 93, in <module>
    x.append(float(line[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? If you get an error message, post it. Otherwise explain what the result is and what is unexpected about it.

Comment: ``file.readlines()`` will read all available input from the file into a list of lines. I think you want to just iterate over the file: ``for line in curfile:``

Comment: What is ``row_first`` and ``row_last``?

Comment: Have you tried putting `x.append(float(line[0]))` in a `try` block and `print(line[0])` in the matching `except` block?

Comment: Add `print(line)` before the `x.append` line and show us the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a guess, but...

Could there be three spaces at the start of the negative lines too? That would cause the `split` to return a list with an empty string at the start.

To resolve this you should `lstrip()` the entire line before splitting. And by the way, if you just do `split()` with no arguments it defaults to "split by any number of spaces", so you don't have to worry about the number of spaces.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me, given that he even managed to misindent a line in the middle of his Python code.

Comment: Yep that did the trick. I tried using lspit on just the first column when appending to x but not the whole row. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the problem you are trying to solve, the code below does it in a clearer manner:

```
x = []
y = []

# Using `with` to ensure that the resources
# are cleaned up after execution
with open('test.txt', 'r') as curfile:
    # Looping through each line of
    # the opened file
    for row in curfile:
        # Check if row/line is empty
        # and only execute the code 
        # if it is not
        if row not in ['\n', '\r\n']:
            # The output of row.split() is 
            # a list, we store this list in
            # split_row
            split_row = row.split('   ')
            # Here we're appending the first
            # column's value into the list
            # x
            x.append(float(split_row[0]))
            # printing the output for debugging
            # purposes
            print split_row[0]
            # Appending the second column's value
            # into the list y
            y.append(float(split_row[1]))
            # printing the output for
            # debugging purposes
            print split_row[1]
```

As to why are you are facing issue with your code? I believe it's due to reading an extra blank line at the bottom of the original file, this is solved with `if row not in ['\n', '\r\n']:` in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to your full source code and your dataset it's a bit hard to tell exactly what's going wrong from that Traceback. It seems like from the *samples* you've posted that your code *should* work; However here is what I think you're trying to achieve:

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

raw = """\
-3.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00\n
-1.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00\n
 1.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00\n
 """

lines = filter(None, map(str.strip, raw.split("\n")))
data = [map(float, filter(None, line.split())) for line in lines]
for row in data:
    print(row)
```

**Demo:**

```
$ python foo.py 
[-3.0, 551.0, 266.0, 0.0]
[-1.0, 551.0, 266.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 551.0, 266.0, 0.0]
```

**Note:** That a lot of what I'm doing here is actually cleaning up the data into a form that can be more easily manipulated. I would however use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module here (*even if you specify a `delimiter` of 3 spaces*).

Answer (score 0):

You might try just using `split()` vs `split('   ')`.

The documentation of [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator returns [].

Now try with your data with leading or trailing spaces:

```
>>> txt='''\
...           -3.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00   
... -1.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00   
...     1.0000000E+00   5.5100000E+02   2.6600000E+02   0.0000000E+00   '''
```

Now try `split()`:

```
>>> [line.split() for line in txt.splitlines()]
[['-3.0000000E+00', '5.5100000E+02', '2.6600000E+02', '0.0000000E+00'], ['-1.0000000E+00', '5.5100000E+02', '2.6600000E+02', '0.0000000E+00'], ['1.0000000E+00', '5.5100000E+02', '2.6600000E+02', '0.0000000E+00']]
```

Note the leading and trailing spaces have been removed.

Now try with `split(   )`:

```
>>> [line.split('   ') for line in txt.splitlines()]
[['', '', '', ' -3.0000000E+00', '5.5100000E+02', '2.6600000E+02', '0.0000000E+00', ''], ['-1.0000000E+00', '5.5100000E+02', '2.6600000E+02', '0.0000000E+00', ''], ['', ' 1.0000000E+00', '5.5100000E+02', '2.6600000E+02', '0.0000000E+00', '']]
```

The leading spaces or trailing spaces are preserved, and this is screwing up a call to `float`.